# Find all real functions $f:\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ satisfying the relation $f(x^2+y(f(x)))=x(f(x+y))$.

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

While doing some old INMO (Indian National Mathematical Olympiad) problems I am stuck on a question which is as follow:

> Find all functions $f:\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ satisfying the relation $f(x^2+y(f(x)))=x(f(x+y))$.

Though I have worked on many problems related to functions, but still I m clueless at this one. I shall be highly thankful if you can give me some hints/suggetions. Thanks.

Comment: Some initial ideas: try plugging in $x=0$ and see what that tells you; try plugging in $y=0$ and see what that tells you. You can also try $x=y=0$. I don't know the answer, but that does give you some more properties to work with.

Comment: @kccu, I would suggest you to make it an answer since I think it is taking me to the solution.

Comment: Someone already beat me to it with a full proof.

Comment: I wouldn't call "old" a problem from the last year :P

Comment: How did you got that it is from last year??

Comment: @kccu, the moment I saw your comment, I started working on it. Now I see that paolo is saying same thing.

Comment: You can find the list of all INMOs (and similar contests) online ;)

Comment: I thought you were there.

Comment: Sadly, I am not that young :P

Comment: Funny that no one asked thus far where the missing parenthesis on the LHS is supposed to go ;-)

Comment: Sorry @dxiv I shall edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Claim:** $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=x$ for all $x \in \mathbf{R}$.

1. Set $x=0$, then $f(yf(0))=0$ hence $f\equiv 0$ is a solution. Otherwise $f$ is not constant and $f(0)=0$.
2. Set $y=0$, then $f(x^2)=xf(x)$ for all $x$. In particular $x^2=(-x)^2$ hence $xf(x)=-xf(-x)$. Therefore $f$ is a odd function.
3. Suppose there exists $x_0\neq 0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$. Setting $x=x_0$ we have $f(x_0^2)=x_0f(x_0+y)$; but $f$ is not constant, hence it is a contradiction.
4. Set $x+y=0$, then $f(x^2-xf(x))=0$. Using (2) and (3), we have $f(x^2-f(x^2))=0$ hence $x^2-f(x^2)=0$. Therefore $f(z)=z$ for all $z\ge 0$. Using that $f$ is odd by (2), then $f$ is the identity.